# How is this XSS attack working?

Tags: javascript, django, xss

***SPOILER ALERT: This question contains an answer to one of the problems from the [Google's XSS Challenge](https://xss-game.appspot.com)! Please stop reading further if you're not interested in knowing the answer right now.***

---

I'm able to get pass the [level 4 of the challenge](https://xss-game.appspot.com/level4), however, I still don't know how exactly the exploit is working. The following is the code from Google's XSS challenge - Level 4:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Internal game scripts/styles, mostly boring stuff -->
    <script src="/static/game-frame.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/game-frame-styles.css" />

    <script>
      function startTimer(seconds) {
        seconds = parseInt(seconds) || 3;
        setTimeout(function() { 
          window.confirm("Time is up!");
          window.history.back();
        }, seconds * 1000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="level4">
    <img src="/static/logos/level4.png" />
    <br>
    <img src="/static/loading.gif" onload="startTimer('{{ timer }}');" />
    <br>
    <div id="message">Your timer will execute in {{ timer }} seconds.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically, they are using Django framework ([which uses a bunch of security measure against XSS](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/27807/22401)). The variable `timer` carries the input from the user. The goal of this activity is to alert a message by sending a payload which can bypass Django's XSS security.

I'm able to alert a message using one of the following payloads:

```
');alert('xss
```

OR

```
3') || alert('1
```

I'm able to clear the level using the above payloads but I'm still not sure where exactly the alert() method is being called? In the `onload` handler OR within the `startTimer()` method?

I'm confused because if I check the source HTML of the page after submitting the payload, Django is encoding the payload:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Internal game scripts/styles, mostly boring stuff -->
    <script src="/static/game-frame.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/game-frame-styles.css" />

    <script>
      function startTimer(seconds) {
        seconds = parseInt(seconds) || 3;
        setTimeout(function() { 
          window.confirm("Time is up!");
          window.history.back();
        }, seconds * 1000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="level4">
    <img src="/static/logos/level4.png" />
    <br>
    <img src="/static/loading.gif" onload="startTimer('&#39;);alert(&#39;xss');" />
    <br>
    <div id="message">Your timer will execute in &#39;);alert(&#39;xss seconds.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see why the XSS worked! [One of the section in the OWASP XSS cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Why_Can.27t_I_Just_HTML_Entity_Encode_Untrusted_Data.3F) says:

> HTML entity encoding is okay for untrusted data that you put in the
>   body of the HTML document, such as inside a  tag. It even sort of
>   works for untrusted data that goes into attributes, particularly if
>   you're religious about using quotes around your attributes. But HTML
>   entity encoding doesn't work if you're putting untrusted data inside a
>    tag anywhere, or an event handler attribute like onmouseover,
>   or inside CSS, or in a URL. So even if you use an HTML entity encoding
>   method everywhere, you are still most likely vulnerable to XSS. You
>   MUST use the escape syntax for the part of the HTML document you're
>   putting untrusted data into. That's what the rules below are all
>   about.

In this case, the user input is being fed into an event handler, which will treat it as a JS instead of HTML. And, the input is being escaped in HTML context (not in JS context). Therefore, JS will treat `startTimer('3&#39;) || alert(&#39;1');` as `startTimer('') || alert('1');` and will simply run this script.

PS: JS escaping might have prevented the attack.

Answer (score 4):

What seems to be confusing you is the mix of two different languages: HTML and JavaScript. `&#39;` is HTML. It's translated to the `'` character when displayed *and when interpreted as JavaScript*. That means, from the JavaScript interpreter's point of view, there's no difference between  `'` and `&#39;`. The code `onload="startTimer('&#39;);alert(&#39;xss');"` is effectively the same as `onload="startTimer('');alert('xss');"` even though at the first glance it looks like something that shouldn't work.

Comment: Oh! That's really confusing. I thought that the string `&#39;);alert(&#39;xss` is passed to the method `startTimer` and alert is being called in the method.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Because of it, I was able to find why exactly it was working!